# pdf viewer for text documents saved as images -- bad rendering

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf, images, evince

The situation I have in mind is a .pdf document obtained from a scan, or at least such that some readers view it as an image (as opposed to text) and render it badly (see the screenshot below)
[image]

My personal user experience is with Evince in Ubuntu 12.04, but I guess this is common problem.

Is there something I can do inside Evince, like turn some option, etc.?
Could you point to a valid alternative with a better rendering for images .pdf?

Using Evince on another Linux distribution and machine I get an acceptable rendering of the same document. Might this image rendering process be related to how the pdf reader interacts with the X-stuff setup?

Comment: Do you want to try to improve the quality of the bitmap so that it's more readable, or to do optical character recognition to obtain text?

Comment: @Gilles I'm no expert, but the second option seems better to me; note that with other readers/computers, the quality is much better. Whatever suggestion you have I'm open